# Building Queue To Deliver Request Only When Backend Is Not Busy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, queue

I am building a queue between my frontend server and backend server to ensure that only one job request would be executed on the backend at a time. There are not enough resources to run multiple jobs.

What I currently have is this:

1. Frontend uploads file to S3, and sends a request to SQS FIFO queue with the link to the object on S3.
2. SQS FIFO queue triggers AWS Lambda function, that retrieves the message with the link from the queue, and sends it to the backend.
3. Backend receives request, downloads the file from the S3 using the link in the message from the queue, and begins processing.

The delivery of messages works, but the issue is when a another upload occurs on the frontend, it is delivered to the backend even if backend is occupied by previous upload.

Usage of the server is not expected to be great. But one job can take between 2 to 20 minutes (based on how many files are in the upload. The acceptable range is 1 to 10). I use Next.js on the frontend, Python for Lambda and for the backend.

Questions:

1. How can I build the mechanism this would prevent AWS Lambda function from sending the request to the backend if backend is occupied?
2. How can I minimize the costs of it? I could add sleep time to Lambda and just poll API route that resoponds with `True` or `False` to being occupied. But Lambda would be charged significantly based on the active time. Or would not it be?
3. What I am building is good thing, or is there more optimal way to create what I need?

Ps. Free to ask more clarifying questions, if needed I could provide certain parts of the code, and ask me elaborate on certain parts if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda's internal SQS poller can't be controlled by the user. It will automatically scale up and try to invoke additional instances if the queue is non-empty. This article describes in more detail how the poller works:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/understanding-how-aws-lambda-scales-when-subscribed-to-amazon-sqs-queues/

You *could* set the batch size to `1` on your queue subscription settings, and also set your lambda functions maximum concurrency value to `1` to guarantee that only a single message is being processed at a time. However, the poller will still be attempting to spin up additional lambda instances, but they will get throttled if an execution is in progress due to your max concurrency setting. This will result in a lot of throttling errors for the messages in your queue, so you'd have to set the `maxReceiveCount` very high otherwise messages will end up in the DLQ, and it would be hard to distinguish true errors in processing vs. throttling errors.

I'd recommend to use an ECS Fargate or other EC2-based server for processing, so you can guarantee there's only one worker instance. It would be more work because you have to implement the polling mechanism, and also more expensive since you can't take advantage of Lambda free tier & pay by usage model.

If you don't want to keep a service running indefinitely, you could implement a more on-demand architecture by triggering a step functions workflow for each s3 event (see [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-cloudwatch-events-s3.html)), and have the workflow call Fargate's `runTask` API to trigger processing if there are no tasks currently running (use [`DescribeTasks` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) to check).